# Bundle extras value lost when exiting app

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, bundle

I've recently encountered a weird nullpointerexception. I'm aware that my app is crashing because one of the values is null, after the users backs all the way out of the app and reopens it. When I step through the code I initially retrieve and store information for "2" values that are placed in my Bundle extras.

Now here is the weird part, upon exiting the app and reopening it, the first extra value is lost entirely and is set to null. However, the second extra value remains in tact and makes it to the next activity?

What would or could cause this to happen? I've tried adding additional items for testing purposes but only my second item makes it. I'm am beyond confused.

Note: This is all happening before implementing the used of SavedInstance

Comment: Could you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

You can check that intent is having value or not and perform you operation:

```
if( getIntent().getExtras() != null)
{
  //do here
}
```